# JobScheduler API: How to execute a job once on application start and then execute the same job periodically after that?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have searched for hours on the internet trying to find a solution to the problem I am facing but to no avail.

My problem is as follows:

From my understanding if you want to create a periodic job on Android using JobScheduler API you need to set the `setPeriodic()` method in the `JobInfo.Builder` , however, I have read that starting from Android Nougat the minimum time interval is 15 minutes.

I am trying to execute the job immediately after application opens and then have it periodically execute at some time intervals. So far this is my code

```
   public class ScheduledJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

    //do something
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        return true;
    }
```

And in my `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(this, ScheduledJobService.class);

        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,serviceName)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setPeriodic(10000);
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build();

        scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        int result = scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

        if (result == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d("JobSchedule", "job created");
        } else {
            Log.d("JobSchedule", "job not created");
        }

    }
```

If I remove the setPeriodic() the job gets executed immediately just like I want  it but obviously it won't get executed again, and if I use `setPeriodic()` I have to wait for some time before the first execution.

I am wondering if there is  way for me to make the job get executed immediately after startup and then continue running periodically?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use only JobScheduler ? I achieved same thing Using Alarm Manager. I am wrting some logs to sdcard every one minute from as soon as my app starts.

Comment: I just want to get my task done, if you have a nice way of doing that using Alarm Manager I wouldn't mind

Comment: Alarm manager is the only way to do this (set one alarm, trigger it, then set the next alarm etc..) with the time window you've set.  Job scheduler's min recurring time window is 15 minutes - `JobInfo.getMinPeriodMillis()`, you've currently got 10 seconds - this is simply ignored and set to the 15 minute minimum. PS - do you really need to poll every 10 seconds - that will kill a users battery! PS you'll have to register a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver as Alarms are not persisted across reboots

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same thing using Alarm Manager. You can use below code :

in OnCreate of Activity :

```
public void schedule() {

        Utils.log("Scheduling Service");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getContext(),  100, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
        else{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }
        }

    }
```

This will start your Service, where you will write your business logic:

```
        public class MyService extends IntentService{

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    // Do your business logic here and after that schedule your job again
    scheduleRepeatingJob();

    }

private void scheduleRepeatingJob(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long triggerTime = Utils.getTimestampForNextAlarm(); // TIme when you want to repeat your job
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            //alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);

            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(triggerTime, pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
        }
        else{
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is take care of doze mode and everything.

Comment: Where are you calling the schedule() methods? In the Activity and the Service? Also, what is scheduleRepeatingjob()?

Comment: in the Activity you are placing MyService.class in the Intent but your second code block has the name DataWritingService. So do I create that service or you just forgot to rename it?

Comment: Can you pls mark it as answer, if it worked for you..?